# The correct way to encrypt a string using HmacSHA256 in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, hash, encryption, hmac, sha256

I need to create a keyed hash for a string of XML to send to a 3rd party. This is the code I am using but it is producing a different hash than the example that the 3rd party has sent me. I have been through all the tutorials I can find and re-read MSDN again and again. What am I doing wrong? Or should I suspect a problem at the other end?

```
Public Shared Function HashString(ByVal StringToHash As String) As String
    Dim myEncoder As New System.Text.UTF32Encoding
    Dim Key() As Byte = myEncoder.GetBytes(My.Settings.PortalHASH)
    Dim XML() As Byte = myEncoder.GetBytes(StringToHash)
    Dim myHMACSHA256 As New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(Key)
    Dim HashCode As Byte() = myHMACSHA256.ComputeHash(XML)
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(HashCode)
End Function
```

It needs to be base-64 encoded, which is why I have the last line.

Thanks

Comment: It seems correct to me. The one question is whether you are using the same key for the hash. My.Settings.PortalHASH suggests it is a hash not a key. But you could have chosen a misleading name and in reality it is the key. So my question really is: How do you get the key?

Comment: The key is indeed a Hash sent to us by the 3rd party. It is the same format as the string returned by the function so I thought it was correct to get it's bytes in this way pass them as the key.

Comment: If the 3rd party sends you the hash of the key they are using you can in now way get the expected result. You need to make sure you get the same key as the 3rd party is using.

Comment: On the other hand, if the "hash" sent to you from the 3rd party is just a Base64 encoded string of the key you need to decode it before using it

Comment: As well as CKret's answer I also needed to change to this Dim myEncoder As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding. All works OK now. Check your encoding people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Read my comments)
If My.Settings.PortalHASH is the Base64 encoded key you need to do this:

```
Dim Key() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(My.Settings.PortalHASH)
```

Comment: Hi CKret that makes a lot of sense - I tried the line above and it still does not match but I can't believe the 3rd party is sending me the key hashed - I will however get on the phone to them and double check all the details, Thanks.

Comment: Hi CKret, as well as the answer above I was using an incorrect Encoding object I wanted ASCII not UTF32 apparently - would have been nice if they told me! Your answer was closest though - cheers.

Comment: Great news that you fixed it! I should have picked up the possible encoding problem but alas did not. Well... good thing you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the correctness of the VB, but from the obviousness of the naming, I can say it looks correct.

So there's not enough information here to say whats wrong; and you've likely said everything you know.  Therefore, the people to verify this for you would be your third party.  They'd be able to say what was wrong.

PS: strange that there is no nonce sent by the other party as a challenge?

Comment: The other end just kicks to a server fault :) at the moment, our side is in very early stages of development and so I can't identify what is wrong as it could be anything! If the above genuinely looks correct then maybe I have the key wrong from them or some such, cheers for your input